# Getting a specific number from each line in a file

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java code that reads a file of students names and grades. It should read the grade of each student and specify if he pass (grade>60) or fails otherwise and write near to each line the result (*"Pass"* or *"Fail"*). But I couldn't get the grade as a number and compare it. 
The file will be like this (each in a new line):

> John, 34
>   David, 55
>   Lina, 87
>   Mary, 77

and the result should write in another file the following (each in a new line):

> John, 34 : Fail
>   David, 55: Fail
>   Lina, 87: Pass
>   Mary, 77: Pass

Here is my code:

```
public static void checkPass(String inFile, String outFile) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));

    int grade;
    String line;

    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        line.split(",");
        line.get(); // here I don't know how to get the grade from the line
        if (grade > 60) {
            out.write(line + " : Pass" + "\r\n");
        } else
            out.write(line + " : Fail" + "\r\n");
    }
    bf.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[1].trim())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] parts = line.split(",");
grade = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());
```

.. and think about exception handling.

Comment: Nice to hear. The Stackoverflow-way of saying this, is to accept the answer (by clicking on the checkmark) and/or marking the answer as useful (by clicking on the upper arrow). You'll even get reputation for doing so ;-)